# Gmail Grid View - Sender Image Troubleshooting (DKIM)

Tags: email, gmail, spf, dkim

I'm attempting to help a client get their Google+ profile logo to display as the sender image in Gmail's grid view.  I've gone over Google's documentation and I'm obviously missing something…  The promotional image does come through so the schema code should be good.

I have verifed the following…

1. The Google+ Page shows as verified
2. The sending domain is a delegated subdomain of the verified domain
3. More than 1,000 emails a week are sent from this domain

Which just leaves the DKIM portion and it's here that I know nothing about what I should be checking.  I know I can go into the source of a gmail email and see the following

```
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of xxxxxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxxx.xxxxx.com designates ###.#.###.### as permitted sender) smtp.mail=xxxxxxxx.xxxxx@xxxxxx.xxxxx.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@x.xxxxxxxx.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=NONE dis=NONE) header.from=x.xxxxxxxx.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha1; c=relaxed/relaxed; s=xxxxxxxx; d=x.xxxxxxxx.com;
```

The problem here is I don't really know how to verify that this is correctly setup against the sending domain/company domain or really whatever else I should be checking.

Can someone please guide me through what I should be looking for here?

Answer (score 0):

Just to be sure, do you know for certain that the page is verified? I thought ours was verified because it showed a little icon next to our web address, but it needs to be the little shield icon next to your logo image on the Google+ page.

As far as the email signing goes, it can either be DKIM or SPF, and it looks like both headers are found. They even use a DMARC header, good stuff! :)